# Subplot colours by column in `pandas`

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am creating a `pandas` plot using the following code:

```
plt = table. \
    reindex_axis(index, axis=1). \
    T. \
    plot. \
    bar(
        subplots=True,
        rot=45,
        stacked=False,
        color=colors,
        width=.4,
        legend=False,
        figsize=(20, 10),
        layout=(3, 4),
        sharex=False,
    )
```

This gives me plots like this:
[image: subplots]

Want I want is more like this:
[image: stacked]

Now I'm quite fine with the bars not being stacked but I really would like the colours to be the same. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Color` param accepts colors for each subplot as array.

```
    color=[colors,colors,colors],
```

In you case will be enough just one item in a list

```
    color=[colors],
```